# Login Issue in magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, login

I have one issue with logout page. When I sign out, sign out page will display after 5 seconds it will redirect to home page. But before the redirect, if you log in then you get logout page and then redirect to the home page.

Comment: You can tweak this logic in vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/logout.phtml file, $($.mage.redirect("<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl())) ?>", "assign", 5000)); , Make sure to override this file